# SQL insert and update high elapsed time happening only at certain time of the day

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, sql-execution-plan

At about 7 PM everyday, I notice that my application runs slower than usual.
Upon checking AWR report, I noticed that 2 frequently used SQL statements are having high elapsed time (about 1 second per execution).

I have compared the AWR report from an earlier  time of the day, 9 AM, and found that the same SQL statements took only 0.01 seconds per execution.

The number of executions for these statements are about the same. Its safe to say that my application has higher load at 9 AM compared to that of 7 PM.

- Both these statements (1 update and 1 insert) are targeting the same
  table.
- This table is quite huge.
- Each of those statements have a    fixed SQL ID, so I would expect
  that the execution plan of each    statement is the same as in the
  morning and also during the night.
- This table has frequent insertions and updates throughout the entire day. Based on the AWR report for that normal and abnormal hour, there are about 100 000 inserts and 60 000 updates.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I could about solving this issue??

I am not the DBA.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. The AWR report should be able to answer the question of load ( 9am vs 7pm ).
2. Having the same SQL ID just means the text of the SQL Statement is the same; not the execution plan. You need to look at the Plan Hash Value (PHV) to see if the execution plans are the same. If they are different, then you need to look at the actual execution plans themselves and understand *why* they are different.
3. What is "quite huge"? Be numeric.

Comment: Hi Bobc, thanks for your reply. The AWR shows that the number of executions during 9 AM is higher than that of 7 PM. However, it is the executions at 7 PM that are having the higher elapsed time. I will check on the Plan Hash Value as you recommended. Also, for your point number 3, may I know what unit of measurement is used to describe the size of a table? Does it go by number of rows? columns? Bytes?

Thanks for your patience!

Comment: A table size would be measured in number or rows and size (MB or GB etc)

Comment: Hi Bobc, apologies for the late reply. Because the table had many rows being inserted, the SQL statistics for the table became stale. Hence, we ran DBMS optimizer twice a day for this particular table to solve this.